# Large ScrollView lags after going fullscreen

Tags: android, scrollview, fullscreen

I have some text inside a ScrollView and it scrolls fine until the app goes fullscreen. After this the scroll doesn't response for first several touches, no matter how much time was spend. BUT when the app goes back to the normal mode there are no such problems.

ScrollView defined like this:

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/text"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Switching fullscreen mode:

```java
private void hideSystemUI() {
    mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1)).start();
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    isFullscreen = true;
}

private void showSystemUI() {
    mToolbar.animate().translationY(statusBarHeight).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1)).start();
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    isFullscreen = false;
}
```

Do you have any ideas? With small text it works fine.

UPD: There are a lot of strange logs appear, when the app going fullscreen. All I do, is calling hideSystemUi method so there are no any expensive operations. I'm totally confused..

```
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 526K (92), 17% free 17936K/21508K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
```